# Get array value in $wp_query->posts var_dump

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
foreach($posts as $post){
    var_dump($post);
}
```

This will grab all the posts for the query that is being run and display all the posts information. The var_dump looks like this:

```
object(WP_Post)#84 (24) { 
    ["ID"]=> int(1190) 
    ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-10-20 14:17:55" 
    ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-20 03:17:55" 
    ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_title"]=> string(21) "Chilled water systems" 
    ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" 
    ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
    ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
    ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_name"]=> string(21) "chilled-water-systems" 
    ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-10-21 11:23:49"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-21 00:23:49" 
    ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_parent"]=> int(1182) 
    ["guid"]=> string(48) "http://siteurl.com" 
    ["menu_order"]=> int(0) **
    ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page"** 
    ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
}
```

I am wondering how can I get the post_type value from that var_dump. (text in bold) I have tried:

```
print_r($post['post_type']);
print_r($post[0]['post_type']);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $post->post_type
```

More details:

If order the output, you can see:

```
object(WP_Post)#84 (24)
{
["ID"]=> int(1190) 
["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-10-20 14:17:55" 
["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-20 03:17:55" 
["post_content"]=> string(0) "" 
["post_title"]=> string(21) "Chilled water systems" 
["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" 
["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
["post_name"]=> string(21) "chilled-water-systems" 
["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
["pinged"]=> string(0) "" 
["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-10-21 11:23:49" 
["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-21 00:23:49" 
["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
["post_parent"]=> int(1182) 
["guid"]=> string(48) "http://siteurl.com" 
["menu_order"]=> int(0) 
["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" 
["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" 
["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
}
```

You have a object, and for access to object's fields, you must use `->`, So, You can use `$post->post_type` for post type target.

Complete code:

```
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
foreach($posts as $post){
    var_dump($post->post_type);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: one more thing. The variable $posts will have multiple objects in the array. How would I get one, for example if it was a normal array you would use `$posts[0]`

Comment: @AJDEV You can use this: $posts[0]->post_type